# Implement regex in django template

Tags: regex, django, django-templates

I am making the navigation of the page as active by checking if the url matches with the current url.

```
<li>
  {% url 'blog' as blog_url %}
  <a href="{{blog_url}}" {% if request.get_full_path == blog_url %}class="active"{% endif %}>Blog</a>
</li>
```

Now I am using pagination, which when going to different page results in url being like this:

From `/blog/` to

```
/blog/?page=2
/blog/?page=3
```

And the above code does not work. So is there anyway to use regex in the template to get anything (like `/blog/*`) and make it as active. Your help and guidance will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

you can just do

```
{% if '/blog/' in request.path %}class="active"{% endif %}
```

no need for regexp