# Django Template--Conditional Based on The Current URL Path

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to exclude some content from the 'Blog' section of my site and would like to exclude this info on any paths that start with /blog, which would include the main `/blog` page and any other associated pages including `blog/<blog-post>` etc.  I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462398/django-template-if-tag-based-on-current-url-value) and tried some of the advice mentioned here but can't exactly get it to work.  Here are my two blog URLs:

```
url(r'^$', BlogListView.as_view(), name='blog'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', blog_post, name='blog_post')
```

and what I've tried (unsuccessfully) in my django template:

```
{% url 'blog:blog_post' slug=slug as the_url %}
{% if request.path == the_url %}
   <div>&nbsp;</div>

{% else %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="nav-2">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">

          {% block side_block %}

          {% get_category_list %}

            {% endblock %}

      </ul>

    </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, i figured it out thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884711/implement-regex-in-django-template)

```
{% if '/blog/' in request.path %}DO SOMETHING HERE{% endif %}
```